# How to untangle parallel make -j compiler messages?

Tags: makefile, cmake, stdout, stderr, build-system

When I use `make -j` to parallelize compilation commands, (unsurprisingly) any compiler messages (warnings/errors) from concurrent commands get interleaved. I'm wondering if there's a way to *untangle* these messages.

For example, with `make -j` I might see something like:

```
Scanning dependencies of target test
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/C.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/B.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/A.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/D.cpp.o
/tmp/B.cpp:3:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
/tmp/C.cpp:3:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
1 warning generated.
/tmp/A.cpp:3:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
/tmp/D.cpp:3:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
[100%] Linking CXX executable test
[100%] Built target test
```

Each `.cpp` triggers a warning but they're interleaved in an arbitrary order. Instead if I issue `make`, then I get the desired sequential output:

```
make 
[ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/A.cpp.o
/tmp/A.cpp:3:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/B.cpp.o
/tmp/B.cpp:3:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/C.cpp.o
/tmp/C.cpp:3:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/D.cpp.o
/tmp/D.cpp:3:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable test
[100%] Built target test
```

but obviously I don't get to take advantage of parallel building.

Is there any way to gather up warnings/errors from each command during the parallel build?

(I'm not super attached to `make`. If `ninja` or other cmake-supported command line (non-GUI IDE) build systems can do this, I'm hear to accept them).

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [output sync option](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel-Output.html).

Comment: `make` on Mac OS X doesn't appear to have this option. Would I need to install a newer/different version?

Comment: No it doesn't say that.  It says that *none* is the default type.  It says that *target* is the default _if you use `-O` by itself_ without giving a specific type.

Comment: `brew install make` and then `gmake -j -Otarget` gives me what I want. Minor issue: when I use `-Otarget` the color highlighting turns off. Is this a known issue? Possible to turn it back on?

Comment: @AlecJacobson Try adding this GCC flag: `--diagnostics-color=always`.

Comment: @MadScientist My bad, I guess I need more sleep.

Comment: Apple supplies only truly old and outdated versions of all GNU programs, including `make` and also `bash` (the shell).  It's because Apple fears the GPLv3 and refuses to ship any software licensed under it, even though they were more than happy to take it.  So they will never update to any version newer than whatever the latest GPLv2 licensed version (for GNU make it's 3.81).  So if you have to use MacOS, you will have to use homebrew or similar to get newer versions.

Comment: Regarding color: see the last paragraph in the manual page I linked to above.  There is also a facility in GNU make 4.1 that will tell programs make invokes that the output is going to a terminal, so those programs could check that to see whether to display color or not, but as far as I know no program has taken advantage of it.  I have patches for both `cmake` and `gcc` that add this support but you'd have to recompile them locally.

Comment: `--diagnostics-color=always` preserves the color of the `error` and `warning` tags from GCC (will need to find equivalent on clang for os x), but I still don't see the color (from make via cmake?) of the `[ 50%] Building C...` lines.

Comment: See my previous comment regarding color.  I'm not sure if there's any equivalent option in `cmake` to `gcc`'s which forces color to be on regardless of the terminal setting.

Comment: Actually, looking more carefully at cmake code I see that it obeys the clicolors standard: https://bixense.com/clicolors/  This means if you use `export CLICOLOR_FORCE=1` before invoking make, your cmake output (should be) colorized regardless of your terminal settings.

Comment: Awesome! Using all of these combined, I was able to create the perfect answer (for OS X): `brew install gmake` then `cmake ../ -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fcolor-diagnostics` then `CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 gmake -j4 -O`. The build is parallel, the output messages are synchronized, and the color is retained.

Comment: I sent a pull request to CMake containing my update to allow it to recognize this feature of GNU make so that should appear in an upcoming CMake release.

Answer (score 1):

Not a killer solution but I do this in scripts:

```
(make -j 10 || make VERBOSE=1)
```

What this will do is to compile in parallel and not print much assuming all is good.
If that fails a sequential compilation is performed with a verbose output (compilation command line is shown)

This solves two problems, one is that one is not usually interested in the command line of compilations steps that succeed
and second (your problem) that all errors are shown at the same time.